# Using MPI_Reduce and MPI_Scatter in C with mpi

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm new in mpi, from this code I want to distribute one row of 2D array to all processor for example

```
p1 = 1,2,3,4
p2 = 5,6,7,8
p3 = 9,10,11,12
p4 = 13,14,15,16
```

when run the program with `(mpirun -np 4 ./a)`,
    `MPI_Scatter`
works fine but
    `MPI_Reduce`
cause stopping in terminal. I do not know how can I deal with `MPI_Reduce` by found localmax or ( mymax). Can any one help?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 4

int main ()
{
    int np, rank, sendcount, recvcount, source,i;
    int recvbuf[size];
    int mymax;
    int max=0;

    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    int sendbuf[size][size] ={
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9,10,11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15, 16}};
    source = 1;
    sendcount = size;
    recvcount = size;

    MPI_Scatter(sendbuf,sendcount,MPI_INT,recvbuf,recvcount,MPI_INT,source,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("rank= %d  Results: %d %d %d %d \n",rank,recvbuf[0],recvbuf[1],recvbuf[2],recvbuf[3]);

    //Each processor has a row, now find local max
    mymax = recvbuf[0]; 
    for(i=0;i<recvcount;i++) {
        if(mymax < recvbuf[i]) {
            mymax = recvbuf[i];
        }
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&mymax,&max ,1,MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank==0) {
        printf(" Processor %d has max data after reduce : max= %d ", rank,max);
    }
    else 
        printf("----.\n");

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: First you should format your code correctly (indentation and html).

Comment: `MPI_Reduce()` is a collective operation that must be called by all the tasks if the communicator. If only rank `0` invokes it, then your program will deadlock.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet , Can you show me how can do by code please?

Comment: As I wrote earlier, start formatting and indenting your code correctly. Then what are you trying to compute ? Max value ? Max value and rank that holds it ?

Comment: I'm trying to find the max value from array

Comment: and what is wrong with the latest revision of your program ? (except the obvious indentation indentation)